# ERROR AL UTILIZAR FUNCION EN ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, function

Espero me puedan ayudar, he creado la función `f_obtener_salario`, la cual debería de traer el salario de un empleado de acuerdo a su identificación

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_OBTENER_SALARIO(P_CI NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
   V_SALARIO NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT C.ASIGNACION INTO V_SALARIO FROM B_CATEGORIAS_SALARIALES C
   JOIN B_POSICION_ACTUAL P ON P.COD_CATEGORIA = C.COD_CATEGORIA
   JOIN B_EMPLEADOS E ON E.CEDULA = P.CEDULA
   WHERE P.CEDULA = P_CI
   AND P.FECHA_FIN IS NULL;
    RETURN V_SALARIO;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'No se puede encontrar dicho empleado');
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Error inesperado');
END;
```

Al querer emplearla, solo me funciona si la utilizo de esta forma:

```
SELECT F_OBTENER_SALARIO(2981474) FROM DUAL;
```

He intentado de la siguiente forma, y también con un bloque PL/SQL anónimo y ninguna me arroja el resultado que busco. Utilizo Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21. Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Este es el error que me aparece, pero creo que son las excepciones establecidas:

```
ORA-20001: No se puede encontrar dicho empleado

ORA-06512: en "BASEDATOS2.F_OBTENER_SALARIO", lÝnea 12
```

```
SELECT CEDULA, NOMBRE || ' ' || APELLIDO AS NOMBRE_COMPLETO, F_OBTENER_SALARIO(CEDULA) AS SALARIO
FROM B_EMPLEADOS;
```

Comment: Hola. En internet en general, escribir todo en mayúsculas se considera gritar. He editado tu publicación para dejar el texto normal. Por favor no olvides esto al hacer publicaciones futuras.

Comment: Con respecto a tu pregunta, el error lo estás lanzando tu mismo(a) dentro de la función cuándo la consulta no devuelve datos. Si no esperas ver un error, entonces, no lo lances. ¿Qué es lo que esperas que ocurra?

Comment: @jachguate aunque el no lance esa excepcion, igual sera lanzada, por el NO_DATA_FOUND, no creo que sea una buena forma de responder. Por otro lado Dabel, estàs seguro que ese dato está en la base, el error es porque simplemente no encuentra el registo y es correcto que lo lance.

Comment: @Javier, no he respondido la pregunta, simplemente dejé un comentario con una observación que consideré importante y porque _siento_ que probablemente el AP no comprende aún su propio código. Sé perfectamente que si no estuviera el manejador del NO_DATA_FOUND ocurriría una excepción y sé también que en ese manejador podría _evitarse_ el error. Lo que no sé, es si el AP también lo sabe. Si hubiera claridad sobre eso, ya hubiese escrito una respuesta.